# How do I show the results of pattern-matching goals in SWI-Prolog from a shell invocation?

Tags: shell, prolog, swi-prolog

I am wondering how one gets output from SWI-Prolog when invoking it from the shell.

Say I have a simple knowledge base, `kb.pl`:

```
dad(elvis, lisaMarie).
dad(john, julian).
```

I can invoke SWI-Prolog from the shell:

```
$ swipl --quiet -s kb.pl -t listing
```

and a listing of my knowledge base is printed to `stdout`. If I try this:

```
$ swipl --quiet -s kb.pl -t "dad(elvis, X)"
$ echo $?
0
```

No output is printed, but I know that it found matches because I get zero when I then query for the return code. Similarly:

```
$ swipl --quiet -s kb.pl -t "dad(morrisey, X)"
$ echo $?
1
```

Shows that that the Prolog is correctly failing to find a matching fact.

My question is this: How do I get all the matches to print, so that from the shell I can see output like when I am in the Prolog environment? E.g.

```
$ swipl --quiet -s kb.pl -t "dad(elvis,X)" --magicdust
X = lisaMarie.
```

I don't think `--quiet` is the problem. It is just suppressing prolog startup messages. See [SWI-Prolog Command-Line Options](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.4%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/cmdline.html%27%29%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print it yourself, for example with:

```
$ swipl -q -s kb.pl -t "dad(elvis,X), writeln(X), false"
```

Comment: Please note that `writeln/1` may lead to unexpected results should `X` use an atom that needs quoting. Think of fact `dad(elvis,'this\nthat').` See [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11047651/772868)