# How do I show the results of pattern-matching goals with several free variables in SWI-Prolog from a shell invocation?

Tags: shell, prolog, non-interactive

Let's use the following prolog base :

```
father(anakinSkywalker, princessLeia).
father(anakinSkywalker, lukeSkywalker).
saysOhNo(lukeSkywalker).
```

[sdesciencelover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466949/sdesciencelover) asked [how to show the results of pattern-matching goals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11234469/324969) in swi-prolog from a shell invocation, and got an answer giving a manual transformation on the query, to isue a write.

```
swipl -q -s kb.pl -t "father(anakinSkywalker,X), writeln(X), false"
```

Result:

```
princessLeia
lukeSkywalker
```

This works fine when one only has a few queries with a single free variable, but manually transforming each one becomes tedious, and if we want proper output with the name of each variable along with its result, it soon becomes very annoying. For example to run the query `father(AVariable, Another)`, one needs to write:

```
swipl -q -s kb.pl -t "father(AVariable,Another), write('AVariable='), write(AVariable), write(', Another='), writeln(Another), false"
```

Result:

```
AVariable=anakinSkywalker, Another=princessLeia
AVariable=anakinSkywalker, Another=lukeSkywalker
```

I tried to feed it the commands from a pipe, but it doesn't work great (I can't detect when it has finished writing the results, so it just hangs afterwards, and no newline separates the answers) :

```
(echo "father(X,Y)."; while true; do echo ";"; done) | swipl -q -s kb.pl
```

Result :

```
X = anakinSkywalker,
Y = princessLeia X = anakinSkywalker,
Y = lukeSkywalker.

swipl hangs here, and needs to be stopped with Control-C.
```

I know I could use a `sed` script to pre-process queries, adding the necessary code to print the variables in capital letters, but it would need a fair amount of work to work on complex queries, for example where two predicates must be satisfied :

```
father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y).
```

To always give correct results, one would need to write a parser for prolog, which would be useless work since prolog already know how to do this interactively.

**So here's my question :** is there a way to tell GNU prolog or SWI prolog (or any other free version that can be easily installed on linux) to run some queries and print the results, just like they would do interactively, but without requiring me to type (or copy-paste) each query by hand ?

**Edit :** a way to store a series of queries in a file (either in the `kb.pl` file or an auxiliary file) and run them all, showing their results would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command-line option `--query-goal` in GNU.  Like so:

```
$ echo a| gprolog --query-goal 'X = 1 ; X =2'
GNU Prolog 1.4.1
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Daniel Diaz
| ?- X = 1 ; X =2.

X = 1 ? a

X = 2

yes
```

Comment: To load a file before running the query, `--consult-file` would be useful, but it seems to be absent from my version of `gprolog` (1.3.0) which is shipped with current versions of ubuntu, so I use `echo a | gprolog --query-goal "consult('kb'); father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)"`.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: The current version of GNU Prolog is 1.4.1! Get it [from the source](http://www.gprolog.org/).

Answer (score 3):

So far, here are the methods I found :

## In [`gprolog`](http://www.gprolog.org/)

Using [false's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11760727/324969), I found that one must add a line at the top of the `kb.pl` file:

```
a(_) :- fail.
```

and then use `./query.sh kb.pl "father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)"`, where `query.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "a(fail)." | gprolog --query-goal "consult('$1'), $2"
```

When the query returns immediately (i.e. no results or a single result and `gprolog` managed to detect it was the last one), this will run the query `consult('kb.pl'), actual_query.`, and then run the query `a(fail).` which will simply print an extraneous `no` on the console, thanks to the always-false predicate we added at the top of the file.

When `gprolog` asks what to do (i.e. several results, or a single result and `gprolog` couldn't detect it was the last one), this will run the query `consult('kb.pl'), actual_query.`, read the `a` which asks `gprolog` to print all results, and then it will run the query `(fail).` which will simply print an extraneous `no` on the console, because these are just grouping parenthesis, so the query is equivalent to `fail.`.

## In [`xsb`](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/)

One can use `./query.sh kb.pl "father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)"`, where `query.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
(echo "consult('$1'), ${2%.}."; yes halt.) | xsb --noprompt --quietload --nobanner
```

When `xsb` asks what to do next, if the user types a non-empty string, followed by `enter`, it will print the next result, otherwise it will stop searching solutions to the current query. Therefore, with the `yes halt.` command, we type an infinite stream of non-empty lines. `xsb` will print all results to the query (each time reading `halt.`, so as it is a non-empty string, it will continue with the next result), and return to its prompt. Then, the following `halt.` it receives will tell it to quit.

## In [`swi-prolog`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/)

I haven't found a solution yet.

[rant]All this would be so much simpler, if the people building prolog implementations actually thought about using them non-interactively, like it's possible with most other languages.[/rant]

Answer (score 1):

You may have found a solution for your problem but anyway, here goes my approach. You can always recurse to the bagof built-in predicate. You may read what it does in the docs, this way you will learn more about it.

```
swipl -q -s starwars.pl -t "bagof(X, Y^father(X,Y), BagOfFathers), bagof(Y, X^father(X,Y), BagOfChildren), writeln(BagOfFathers), writeln(BagOfChildren)."
[anakinSkywalker,anakinSkywalker]
[princessLeia,lukeSkywalker]
```

You can also process it later as a mapping or whatever you want, the relations are 1:1 (No sure if is the correct way of stating it but I hope you get it)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following bash script for swi-prolog:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec swipl -q  -f none -g "load_files([interface],[silent(true)])" \
         -t interface:get_args -- $*
```

this will load the file `interface.pl` and call the predicate `get_args/0`
to get the command line arguments you can call:

```
current_prolog_flag(argv, Arguments)
```

of course you can change the names of the predicates/files loaded.
the `silent(true)` arguments suppresses informational messages such as the intro text

edit:
the error message you get is cause you probably dont have an `interface.pl` file (neither a get_args/0 predicate).
you will have to replace `interface` with `kb` (or however you name the file) and `interface:get_args` with `kb:father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)` *or* use an auxiliary predicate within your prolog file such as `run(X,Y):- father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)` (which may be kinda cleaner)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer… I'm trying to load a file containing facts and rules, and run a query on it, displaying the query's results, and do all that non-interactively (i.e. from a shell script). For example, with false's answer, I can use `echo a | gprolog --query-goal "consult('kb'); father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)".` for gprolog (which suits me fine, but I'd be curious to have the same for swi-prolog). Your answer gives me `ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed: ERROR: source_sink 'interface' does not exist` when I run the script (with `#` before `!/bin/sh`). P.S. I'm a prolog novice.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron yeah, the `#` was skipped during copy-paste, fixed. basically you need to change the filenames since I had generic names; check the edit

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's clearer now. However, when I launch `swipl -q -f none -g "load_files([kb],[silent(true)])" -t "kb:father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)"`, nothing is printed, the only information I get is the error code (`echo $?`) which is 0 if it found a solution, and 1 if it didn't. Therefore this is basically the same as `swipl -f kb.pl -t "kb:father(X,Y), saysOhNo(Y)" >/dev/null 2>&1`, however I'd expect it to print what values should be taken for X and Y for each solution it finds.